# Alternatives to AVFoundation for creating video on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, video, video-encoding

I need to create video programmatically and be compatible with iOS 3.2. The asset writer stuff from AVFoundation is iOS 4.2 only.

What are the alternatives for creating video?

Comment: if u just want to capture video use UIImagePickerController

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, if UIImagePickerController and/or AVFoundation don't work for you, you'll have to do it all by hand using Core Audio, Core Data and Core Video. If you plan on doing this, I would recommend consulting Cocoa documentation, rather than iOS.